# KML Network Link - Fly To

Tags: kml, google-earth

I am developing an application that launches Google Earth with a KML file that links to other local files via `<NetworkLink>`, which does Time Interval refreshing. I'm trying to define a KML file that will center the map (fly to) a specific location.

[Network Link](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#networklink) has a  tag which flies to the first placemark or FlyTo within the file. However, this would execute the fly to whenever the file is refreshed, which in my case, is when the Time Interval expires. Is there some way that I can have the fly-to command execute only when the linked network file changes, rather than every time? Is there any way to have the Fly To process only once until the linked file is changed somehow? My NetworkLink file is defined as follows:

```
  <NetworkLink>
    <name>My Fly To Request</name>
    <Link>
      <href>MyFlyTo.kmz</href>
      <refreshMode>onInterval</refreshMode>
      <refreshInterval>2</refreshInterval>
    </Link>
  </NetworkLink>
```

The application will frequently update the the specific placemark to be centered on when the user requests. It is not a static placemark that needs to be centered on, but one that will change frequently.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could achieve this by using a combination of `ID` attributes and the `NetworkLinkControl` and `Update` element in Kml.

The MyFlyToRequest.kml file contains the NetworkLink that loads the data file, which contains your data, it has the `flyToView` element set to true. Notice too the network link also has an id of `request`

**MyFlyToRequest.kml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<NetworkLink id="request">
    <name>My Fly To Request</name>
    <Link>
      <href>http://www.yourserver.com/MyFlyTo.kmz</href>
      <refreshMode>onInterval</refreshMode>
      <refreshInterval>2</refreshInterval>
    </Link> 
    <flyToView>1</flyToView>   
</NetworkLink>
</kml>
```

The second file, MyFlyTo.kmz, is the one loaded. It has your current data as is..,However, it would also have an additional NetworkLink that loads a new third file.

**MyFlyTo.kmz - Edited**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document id="data">
  <visibility>1</visibility>
  <NetworkLink>
    <name>Update MyFlyToRequest</name>
    <Link>
      <href>http://www.yourserver.com/TurnOffFlyTo.kml</href>
    </Link>
  </NetworkLink>
  <Placemark>
    <name>This is flown to once (hopefully)</name>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>52,0,0</coordinates>
      </Point>
   </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

The new third file `TurnOffFlyTo.kml` is part of the key to the set up, it contains a `NetworkLinkControl` that targets the `request` NetworkLink in the first MyFlyToRequest.kml file. It simply sets `flyToView` element to 0.

**TurnOffFlyTo.kml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<NetworkLinkControl>
  <Update>
    <targetHref>http://www.yourserver.com/MyFlyToRequest.kml#request</targetHref>
    <Change>
        <NetworkLink id="request">
            <!-- turn off the flyto behaviour -->
            <flyToView>0</flyToView>   
        </NetworkLink>
    </Change>
  </Update>
</NetworkLinkControl>
</kml>
```

The final file `TurnOnFlyTo.kml` simply retoggles the flyto behaviour again.

**TurnOnFlyTo.kml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<NetworkLinkControl>
  <Update>
    <targetHref>http://www.yourserver.com/MyFlyToRequest.kml#request</targetHref>
    <Change>
        <NetworkLink id="request">
            <!-- turn off the flyto behaviour -->
            <flyToView>1</flyToView>   
        </NetworkLink>
    </Change>
  </Update>
</NetworkLinkControl>
</kml>
```

The logic is as follows.

1. MyFlyToRequest.kml loads MyFlyTo.kml
2. `flyto` is enabled so the view  moves the first first placemark, etc, in MyFlyTo.kml
3. The link in MyFlyTo.kml loads TurnOffFlyTo.kml.
4. The `Update` in TurnOffFlyTo.kml three disables `flyto` in MyFlyToRequest.kml.
5. File one, refreshes, loads file two...

If you need to re-enable the flyto, you would simply load File four. If the data in MyFlyTo.kmz is being generated by you it would be a simple case of loading TurnOnFlyTo.kml right where TurnOffFlyTo.kml was called.

All that said, this is not tested and as such might not work as is, although in principal I don't see why it wouldn't.

If it sounds like something you might try here are a few resources that should help.

**NetworkLinkControl Reference**

http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#networklinkcontrol

**Using Updates**

http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/updates.html

Comment: This is a really cool idea. One thing I didn't go in to detail in my OP is that the Placemark data often changes. I think I might not need TurnOnFlyTo.kml, and every time I just reload the first 3 files, but I'm not sure about the order of execution that GE will take.

Comment: Also, MyFlyTo.kmz doesn't appear to be a valid kml document. I don't think you can have a <NetworkLink> and <Document> node.

Comment: Having a networklink and document is fine, there is probably a typo as I just wrote it all out in the answer. Try putting both the place mark and link in a document element.

Comment: I have edited the MyFlyTo.kmz file to show how - the example is taken from http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#networklink